# How to get the data from sql table where data is not present in the between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, not-exists

How to get the data from sql table where data is not present in the between dates

I am using three table

1. Customer Master
2. Daily dispatch
3. EmptyCylinderRecd

I want to find the customers who are not in the `Dailydispatch` and `EmptyCylinderRecd` tables. I have tried this query but the expected results are not showing up:

```
select * 
from CustomerMaster 
where 
   not EXISTS (select * 
               from DailyDispatch  
               where OrderDate between '1/22/2014' and '08/10/2014') or 
   not exists (select * 
               from EmptyCylinderRecd 
               where Date between '1/22/2014' and '08/10/2014')
```

Comment: Can you show the table structure?

Comment: what is relation in between tables???

Comment: The relation between in three table is the Name is the common field

Comment: @Sarvan - You want customers present in table 1, but not in 2,3 ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev exactly rite,i want the customer in table 1 and who not in table 2,3.

Answer (score 0):

```
Name is the common field
```

then try this:

```
select * 
from CustomerMaster where Name NOT IN 
(select Name from DailyDispatch  
where CAST(OrderDate as DATE) between '2014-01-22' and '2014-08-10' 
and Name is NOT NULL )

union 

select * 
from CustomerMaster where Name NOT IN 
(select Name from EmptyCylinderRecd 
where  CAST(Date as DATE)between '2014-01-22' and '2014-08-10'
and Name is NOT NULL)
```

**Note**: It will be better if You use  column Something Like `CustomerID` with Proper indexing
on it. `Union` will give common results from query1 and query2. Use `Not Exists` in the terms of performance as other suggested. [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: Maybe you mean "NOT IN" instead of just "NOT"?

Comment: With the conversion of [OrderDate] and [Date] the arguments ar no longer SARGable, leading to a table scan, even if there's a supporting index present. Furthermore, NOT IN can return incorrect results if the column in the inner select can have NULL values. Therefore, I'd strongly vote against that solution.

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar-thanks for your answer,but i want to check the in the both tables which data not present,i want to display the common names which is not in dailydispatch and EmptyCylreturn tables.This query is showing union.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customermaster C 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   dailydispatch D 
                   WHERE  C.NAME = D.NAME 
                         AND D.orderdate BETWEEN '2014-22-1' AND '2014-08-10') 
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   emptycylinderrecd E 
                       WHERE  C.NAME = E.NAME 
                              AND E.date BETWEEN '2014-22-1' AND '2014-08-10')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the [Name] column in DailyDispatch or in EmptyCylinderRecd can be null (column definition) I'd vote agaist the NOT IN solution since this may lead to incorrect results.

Instead, I'd use the "NOT EXISTS" approach:

```
SELECT cm.* 
FROM CustomerMaster cm
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM DailyDispatch dp 
     WHERE cm.YourCol1 = dp.YourCol1 AND dp.OrderDate BETWEEN '20140122' and '20140810'
     )
OR NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM EmptyCylinderRecd ecr 
     WHERE cm.YourCol1 = ecr.YourCol1 AND ecr.[Date] BETWEEN '20140122' and '20140810'
    )
```

Please note that I changed the date format to be ISO compliant in order to avoid wrong results or errors due to the setting of DATEFORMAT.